# file transfer using udp multicast in python ?

Tags: python, file, multicast, transfer

How do you send and receive a file using UDP Multicast in Python,
 Is there a standard library to do so?, or any other standard function modules?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's info on how to do just that](http://pymotw.com/2/socket/multicast.html) with source examples:

```
import socket
import struct
import sys

message = 'very important data'
multicast_group = ('224.3.29.71', 10000)

# Create the datagram socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Set a timeout so the socket does not block indefinitely when trying
# to receive data.
sock.settimeout(0.2)
try:

    # Send data to the multicast group
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sent = sock.sendto(message, multicast_group)

    # Look for responses from all recipients
    while True:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting to receive'
        try:
            data, server = sock.recvfrom(16)
        except socket.timeout:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'timed out, no more responses'
            break
        else:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s" from %s' % (data, server)

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

Comment: how to send and recieve file not message

Comment: That's a separate question.  :)   Open the file, read the data out of it, and send that data as messages.   The net is full of tutorials for how to do file handling in python.  Also this is just sample code.  No matter what you have to adapt it to your use.